# how to create "Shopping Cart Price Rule" to toggle shipping methods free & flat

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping

I have enabled both shipping methods `free` and `flat rate`.

Now i want to apply a rule, and it's like `if total price added of products in cart exceeds $1000 => Free shipping, else (Less than $1000 flat rate shipping)`.

After i have activated both shipping methods. i made rule like this

[image]

And this shows both shipping methods like before i set the rule.
The rule is `active` and applied to all `customer groups`.

Comment: Why don't you use table rates to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set  Minimum Order Amount inside free shipping so I think there is no need to create any shipping rule for this

Comment: Hello there, setting minimum order amount inside free shipping will show both `free` and `flat` rate after reaching that min.amount . i want to toggle between these. when free shipping activates, how can i disable `flat rate` ?

Comment: Ok, i got the answers from this question http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/13796/hide-other-shipping-methods-when-free-shipping-is-enabled/