# Hide/disable standard shipping when qualified for free shipping

Tags: magento-1.8, module, shipping, free-shipping

I have read the other suggestions for similar problems but I have not solved my issue yet.

I'm using standard shipping (with tablerates.csv) and free shipping on orders over $50 plus a flat rate for customers that want express post.

The problem is that when a customer qualifies for free shipping the standard shipping still shows up as an option. (It should just disappear and only leave "Free" and "Express" as the 2 options.)

I am not using a "Shopping Cart Price Rule" for free shipping as this introduces a different set problems.

Can someone suggest the simplest way to stop Magento from displaying the Standard/Table rates once the free shipping threshold has been reached.

(Or even suggest an extension that solves the issue or clarify answers given to [Hide other shipping methods when free shipping is enabled](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/13796/hide-other-shipping-methods-when-free-shipping-is-enabled))

Any help would be *greatly* appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Create a module with the following `config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Shipping_Onepage>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Shipping_Onepage>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <checkout>
                <rewrite>
                    <onepage_shipping_method_available>Shipping_Onepage_Block_Method</onepage_shipping_method_available>
                </rewrite>
            </checkout>
        </blocks>
    <global>
</config>
```

This is the rewritten class in `Shipping/Onepage/Block/Method.php`, which removes all other methods if free shipping is available:

```
   <?php
    class Shipping_Onepage_Block_Method extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Shipping_Method_Available
{
    public function getShippingRates()
    {
        $rates = parent::getShippingRates();
        if (array_key_exists('freeshipping', $rates)) {
            $rates = array('freeshipping' => $rates['freeshipping']);
        }

        return $rates;
    }
}
```

Source: http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/hide-other-shipping-methods-when-free-shipping-is-enabled/

Comment: in your config.xml code, ther must be </global> inplace of <global>. Check closing tag and please edit. I faced this as an issue!

Answer (score 2):

I always wanted to do this via observer but never managed to do it, so here is the way to do it with rewrite.

Create a module with the following etc/config.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Your_Module>
            <version>0.0.3</version>
        </Your_Module>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <blocks>
            <checkout>
                <rewrite>
                    <onepage_shipping_method_available>Your_Module_Block_Onepage_Shipping_Method_Available</onepage_shipping_method_available>
                </rewrite>
            </checkout>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

Then create the block: Block/Onepage/Shipping/Method/Available.php:

```
<?php
    class Your_Module_Block_Onepage_Shipping_Method_Available extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Shipping_Method_Available
{
    public function getShippingRates()
    {
        $rates = parent::getShippingRates();
        if (array_key_exists('freeshipping', $rates) && array_key_exists('tablerate', $rates)) {
            unset($rates['tablerate']);
        }
        return $rates;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your theme template file app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml, Find the line looks something like `<dl class="sp-methods">` somewhere around line no 32. Add the below code just above the line `<dl class="sp-methods">`:

```
<?php
if( array_key_exists('freeshipping', $_shippingRateGroups )) {
$_shippingRateGroups = array('freeshipping' => $_shippingRateGroups['freeshipping']);
}
?>
```

**And you are done**

Comment: Default available.phtml file is located at: app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml

Answer (score 0):

I've modified Raphaels solution a bit to fit my needs. Maybe someone can use it. I needed to exclude Webshop matrixrates if UPS is already eligible for free shipping (due shopping cart price rule)

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyModule_FreeShipping>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </MyModule_FreeShipping>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <blocks>
            <checkout>
                <rewrite>
                    <onepage_shipping_method_available>MyModule_FreeShipping_Block_Onepage_Shipping_Method_Available</onepage_shipping_method_available>
                </rewrite>
            </checkout>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

**Available.php**

```
class MyModule_FreeShipping_Block_Onepage_Shipping_Method_Available extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Shipping_Method_Available
{
    public function getShippingRates()
    {
        $rates = parent::getShippingRates();

        $free = array();

        foreach ($rates as $code => $_rates) {
            foreach ($_rates as $_rate) {
                if ($_rate->getCode() == 'ups_GND' && !$_rate->getPrice()) {
                    $free[$code] = $_rates;
                }
            }       
        }

        if (!empty($free)) {
            return $this->_rates = $free;
        }

        return $rates;
    }
}
```